# Changing the type of a field in a collection in a mongodb database

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

The type of a field in a collection in my mongodb database is unicode string. This field currently does not have any data associated with it in any of the documents in the collection.
I dont want the type to be string because,i want to add subfields to it from my python code using pymongo.

The collection already has many records in it.So, is it possible to change the type of the field to something like a dictionary in python for all the documents in the collection ?

Please Help
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Sure, simply create a script that iterates over your current collection, reads the existing value and overwrite it with the new value (an embedded document in your case). You change the typ of the field by simply setting a new value for that field. E.g. setting a string field to an integer field :

db.test.update({field:"string"}, {$set:{field:23}})

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "the type of a field ... is a string" and "this field ... does not have any data". Do you mean the field exists in your documents, but is set to an empty string or `null`?

In either case, MongoDB is "schemaless," which means it won't enforce any particular schema on your documents, not even that all documents in a collection have the same structure.

If you are using a framework that requires you to declare a schema (MongoEngine, mongokit, etc), then you'll have to make according changes in your use of the framework, and we'll need to know what framework you're using.

If you're just using pure pymongo, you can just change your document as you see fit. Suppose you have a document like:

```
{name: "dcrosta", address: null }
```

And you want to make `address` a sub-document. You can do this all in a single update:

```
db.people.update({address: None}, {'$set': {'address': {
     'street1': None,
     'street2': None,
     'city': None,
     'state': None,
     'zip': None,
}}}, multi=True)
```

(this is in pymongo, exact syntax will vary a little in the shell or in other drivers)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The field is say metadata, now when i do :s['metadata']['some_date'] = datetime.utcnow(), I get the error: TypeError: 'unicode' object does not support item assignment. The some_date field does not exist, im creating it through my python code and assigning datetime.utcnow() to it.

Comment: In Python, you have to replace `s['metadata']` with a `dict` before you can assign to it. MongoDB documents are represented in Python with native Python data types -- `dict` for a document, `list` for arrays, `str`/`unicode`, `float`, `int`/`long`, etc. Try `s['metadata'] = {}` and then `s['metadata']['sub_key'] = "sub_key's value"`